# Rails rollback error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ckeditor, paperclip

This is my error. It's a rollback transaction

`Gemfile`:

```
gem 'ckeditor', '~> 4.1', '>= 4.1.6'
gem 'paperclip', '~> 5.1'
```

My request log shows

```
Started POST "/ckeditor/pictures?qqfile=Knipsel.png" for ::1 at 2017-03-21 15:50:26 +0100
Processing by Ckeditor::PicturesController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"qqfile"=>"Knipsel.png"}
Command :: file -b --mime "C:/Users/MyName/AppData/Local/Temp/e85eb525e3b5cf46d5c8270aecfc401b20170321-4468-1lbl7wa.png"
[paperclip] Content Type Spoof: Filename Knipsel.png (image/png from Headers, ["image/png"] from Extension), content type discovered from file command: . See documentation to allow this combination.
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
Command :: file -b --mime "C:/Users/MyName/AppData/Local/Temp/e85eb525e3b5cf46d5c8270aecfc401b20170321-4468-1bmn28u.png"
[paperclip] Content Type Spoof: Filename Knipsel.png (application/octet-stream from Headers, ["image/png"] from Extension), content type discovered from file command: . See documentation to allow this combination.
   **(0.0ms)  rollback transaction**
Completed 200 OK in 100ms (Views: 0.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Answer (score 0):

Paperclip validates mime types before allowing a file to be attached to a model.
The browser usually sends a mime type (what it believes the file to be), in your case, that's 'image/png' for the first file and 'application/octet-stream' for the second file.
But because mime type spoofing is a thing, paperclip tries to determine the mime type itself, by running the 'file' command on the files. In your case, that command returns an empty string for both files:

```
, content type discovered from file command: . See documentation to allow this combination.
```

That space between 'command:' and '.' is what the file command returned.

My guess is: You are running on windows and don't have it installed, or it can't be found. Follow [these instructions for exactly that case on the paperclip website](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#file).